# PHPUnit/Cypress Testing 2 Databases in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, testing, phpunit, laravel-8

(crosspost from https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/testing/phpunitcypress-testing-2-databases )

Hi all, so I'm trying to set up testing for my project part-way through (cause I was silly and didn't write tests from the start)

I'll give a quick summary of the project so there is some context...

- A community runs a game server, which uses a database for in-game persistence, logs, and other data.
- I'm writing a utility site so that users can view their in-game
  character information, admins can view logs, edit players, write
  private notes etc, all on a web interface
- This means I have two databases for the site: the game database, which is controlled by the game server and the website simply accesses to read and edit content ... and the website database, which is controlled by the website and its migrations, and only the website accesses.

So the website database has a relationship join to the game database from users...

- A user logs into the website using steam auth and their steamid and login tokens etc are saved on the website database
- A player joins the game and the game stores their steam ID in the game database
- the user entry in the website database is linked one-to-one to the game database player entry based on their steam IDs

I have a local copy of the game database I use for development. Changes to the data won't affect anything live.

---

Anyway, I hope that sort of makes sense... Onto the question...

My issue is when I want to test my application with these databases...

The Website Database is easy enough, regardless of if I use an SQLite :memory: database or a physical database, I can just use the RefreshDatabase trait and PHPUnit/etc will handle refreshing the database with my migrations for it... all good... no problem there as far as I am aware...

The issue comes when I want to have the second (game) database change rollback handled with testing... I don't have migrations for this database, as it's not controlled or managed by the website.

My questions are:

1. How can I have PHPUnit/cypress/etc reset changes to the second database (the game database) caused by automated tests?
2. If I have to write migrations or something for #1 to be doable, how can I tell a migration to only run when the app environment is testing? (i.e. any migration for the game database must **NOT** run when running art migrate in a production or local environment)

Basically, I'm hoping to end up with a setup where I can have PHPUnit insert data needed for the test cases into both local test databases, and then for PHPUnit to roll back the changes.

I'm just not sure how to deal with the second database which is accessed via eloquent, but not managed by laravels migrations etc. It is only accessed by laravel.

Hopefully all this rambling makes sense, and I'll try to elaborate if anything needs clarification.

It's quite possible I'm missing something obvious here.

Comment: Is resetting the second, game database whenever phpunit starts the test-run (not  only a single test) an option? If so, you could do this in  a bootstrap.php script (it's [a feature the phpunit test-runner supports](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/textui.html)).

Comment: Is it possible to have migrations that do nothing? So migrations are defined, by they are a no-op or can represent and undefined migration.

Comment: @hakre when you say reset the database, do you mean run some PHP that effectively truncates the tables? Thats certainly an option, I'll have to look into that phpunit feature.

As for the migrations, not sure, that's one thing I was curious about - if its possible to have migration for a database but have them normally not execute/do nothing...
I suppose I could add in a 'if env() == testing' into the migration itself???

Comment: Well I'd say that depends on the migration library. Sometimes its enough to point it to  a different folder or what you suggest to only run it in/for a specific environment. Are the migrations organized per application or per database?

Comment: ATM all my migrations are in the one folder (since I've only got migrations for the one database).
I'm not actually sure how Laravel handles multi-database migrations... I will have to look into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've sort of gotten it working with the following methods.

I've got two separate databases being used for testing by specifying a `.env.testing` file.

The first (website) database is being reset with Laravels `RefreshDatabase` trait

The second (game) database is being reset with the following code:

```
    public function setUp() : void {
        parent::setUp();
        \DB::connection('mysql2')->beginTransaction();
    }

    public function tearDown() : void {
        parent::tearDown();
        \DB::connection('mysql2')->rollBack();
    }
```

So far it seems to be working, although I've only written a couple of tests...

If anyone has a "better" or "more proper" answer, please let me know! :D

Comment: only a small hint FYI: call `parent::tearDown();` at the end of the tear down method. this aligns with the class hierarchy (parent set-up, self set-up | self tear-down, parent tear-down)